# How can I use Cognitive Services in Azure Government?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-gov

This blog post ["Azure brings big data, analytics, and visualization capabilities to U.S. Government"](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/azure-brings-big-data-analytics-and-visualization-capabilities-to-u-s-government/) indicates that:

> We are also announcing a preview of Cognitive Services in Azure Government. We have enabled scenarios such as audio and text translation into other languages as well as facial (gender and age) and emotion recognition with Computer Vision and Emotion.

However, I don't see it in the UI, what am I missing? How can I use Cognitive Services in Azure Government.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually came across these other blog post: [Expanding Cognitive Services Pilot for Azure Government](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregov/2017/05/11/expanding-cognitive-services-pilot-for-azure-government/) which outlines the following:

> No Azure Portal UI for Cognitive Services – Management is through the Cognitive Services PowerShell cmdlets

Using PowerShell you can then create and start using Cognitive Services as follows:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Environment AzureUSGovernment
New-AzureRMResourceGroup -Name {resourcegroup} -Location 'usgovvirginia'
New-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccount -ResourceGroupName '{resourcegroup}' -name '{name}' -Type {ComputerVision | Emotion | Face | SpeechTranslation | TextTranslation} -SkuName F0 -Location 'usgovvirginia'
$key = New-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccountKey -ResourceGroupName '{resourcegroup}' -name '{resourcename}' -KeyName {Key1 | Key2}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/regions/services/) tracker, Cognitive Services are currently not available in any of the 4 US Azure Government regions

As it mentioned in the same blog post, you have to contact them at the email specified for accessing the preview version -

> If you’re interested in participating in the Azure Government
>   Cognitive Services preview, please contact azgovfeedback@microsoft.com
>   for more information.

Comment: This is not correct, Cognitive Services IS available, see the other answer.

Comment: Glad you were able to access it through Powershell. It is not my fault if the "Products available by region" tracker is not updated

Comment: Found out that the reason it doesn't show up in "Products available by region" is because it's in preview. But thanks again for offering to help out with my inquiry.